# Seed generation for each operation

Tags: random, random-seed, mbedtls

I' musing `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_seed` function in order to generate seed. Should I do this before each encryption operation or it might be done one when program starts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single DRBG instance for the whole program. It's meant for that. In a high-performance multi-threaded program running on a multicore machine, you might prefer one DRBG instance per thread to reduce inter-thread contention.

Per the documentation, [you must call `mbedtls_ctr_drbg_seed` exactly once per context](https://github.com/Mbed-TLS/mbedtls/blob/v3.3.0/include/mbedtls/ctr_drbg.h#L284). This function associates the DRBG with an entropy source. The DRBG will query the entropy source function from time to time when it wants more entropy<sup>1</sup> (in all cases, at least once when you call the `seed` function).

You can see how to the entropy and DRBG APIs of Mbed TLS in sample programs such as [`key_app.c`](https://github.com/Mbed-TLS/mbedtls/blob/v3.3.0/programs/pkey/key_app.c).

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>Depending on the [reseed interval](https://github.com/Mbed-TLS/mbedtls/blob/v3.3.0/include/mbedtls/ctr_drbg.h#L408) and the [prediction resistance setting](https://github.com/Mbed-TLS/mbedtls/blob/v3.3.0/include/mbedtls/ctr_drbg.h#L343)). These are secondary concerns, which matter only to recover if the DRBG state leaks (e.g. through a memory read vulnerability or through side channels).</sub>